# Pushing an object into an array causes the object to only have one value in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

When I try to push an object into an array it works fine. I'm using this in a for loop so it is supposed to put 59 objects into the array. It does put 59 things into the array but only the first one is an object. Here is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < game.Levels[LevelNum - 1].Generation[0].LengthGen; i++) {
  noise = game.Levels[LevelNum - 1].Generation[0].Noise
  var a = new Object(i * 20, 20, 20, Math.round(Math.random() * noise + 1));
  game.Levels[LevelNum - 1].Generation.push(a);
  console.log("Generated " + i)
}
```

Here is the output accessed from the console on the page:

```
[Object, Number*57]
//the times 52 is the number of "Number"'s repeated
```

What I need to happen is for the array to be filled with objects that have a height, length, x, and y coordinate. Then later on this will be used to draw a box. At the moment the code I am using only displays Objects with 1 value in it. When I try to assign a key (I don't know how it's called but when you put "x:" in front of a value) to all four values. When I do that is says ) was expected and the game does not load.

Comment: Code posted as runnable snippets should actually run or display the aberrant behaviour in question. Note that the Object constructor only takes one (optional) argument, the rest are ignored. The output the console should be the string "Generated " and a number.

Comment: To be clear, `var a = new Object(i * 20, 20, 20, Math.round(Math.random() * noise + 1));` will resolve to `var a = new Object(i * 20)`, which returns a new object per the rules for [*ToObject*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toobject).

Comment: @RobG then how would you make it output more than that

Comment: You need a constructor to make an Object to your design that does something with the extra arguments. You are passing values to a generic constructor that doesn't know what to do with them, so they're ignored. Maybe you want an Object `var a = {a:i * 20, b:20, c:20, ...)` or Array `var a = [i * 20, 20, 20, ...];`.

Answer (score 1):

When `value` has a primitive javascript data type,

```
var o = new Object( value)
```

creates a wrapper object for the value consistent with its data type. And as mentioned in @RobG comments, `Object` takes only one parameter when called as a constructor.

So

var a = new Object(i * 20, 20, 20, Math.round(Math.random() * noise + 1));

creates the same result as

var a = new Object(i * 20);

which creates a `Number` object as a wrapper around the a multiple of 20. When logged to the console it will display as a number, but `"typeof a"` should still evaluate to "object", and `a.constructor` should evaluate to "Number" (**not** "Object").

Comment: So How would I do it?

Comment: Try pushing an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or an object with property names for each of the values you want to store.  If this is not the answer you are looking for please update the question with details of what you want to achieve.